# Pi gets /24 address on reboot even though I'm running /26

Tags: networking

I am having a recurring issue with my raspberry pi 3, I have my router (linksys E2500) setup with DHCP reservations for all my network devices.  This raspberry pi has 192.168.1.34/26 and gets this ip address, but when rebooted it receives the 192.168.1.34/26 and 192.168.1.36/24?  I have deleted the.36/24 address repeatedly and every reboot it comes back.  Output from "ip addr show eth0"

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:de:9e:cb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.36/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.1.34/26 brd 192.168.1.63 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fede:9ecb/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

It has been impossible to search this and find any information other than the typical static ip "tutorials" or ref to etc/network/interfaces vs dhcpcd.conf...both of these files are default in this case.  This raspberry pi is setup to run my plexmediaserver and run headless.
Thank you for looking

*Edit as requested*

```
pi@plex-ht:~ $ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Output of etc/dhcpcd.conf

```
pi@plex-ht:~ $ cat /etc/dhcpcd.conf
# A sample configuration for dhcpcd.
# See dhcpcd.conf(5) for details.

# Allow users of this group to interact with dhcpcd via the control socket.
#controlgroup wheel

# Inform the DHCP server of our hostname for DDNS.
hostname

# Use the hardware address of the interface for the Client ID.
clientid
# or
# Use the same DUID + IAID as set in DHCPv6 for DHCPv4 ClientID as per RFC4361.
#duid
 Persist interface configuration when dhcpcd exits.
persistent

# Rapid commit support.
# Safe to enable by default because it requires the equivalent option set
# on the server to actually work.
option rapid_commit

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
 option classless_static_routes
# Most distributions have NTP support.
option ntp_servers
# Respect the network MTU.
# Some interface drivers reset when changing the MTU so disabled by default.
#option interface_mtu

# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
require dhcp_server_identifier

# Generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses instead of hardware based ones
slaac private

# A hook script is provided to lookup the hostname if not set by the DHCP
# server, but it should not be run by default.
nohook lookup-hostname
```

Comment: You say `etc/network/interfaces` is default, but do not list it. This looks like 2 mechanisms are attempting to resolve.

Comment: For now I have rigged it to delete the rogue ip address @reboot in crontab.  This is working fine, but the OCD AR part of me knows it's still an issue.  What I plan to do next is use a spare SD and bare install of jessie to see if it's something in my config or specific to the pi/eth0.  I'll post back results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BLUF:only add the ip address for your pi to /boot/cmdline.txt if you can remember to update when you want to re-ip your network...

I started reviewing the steps I took to setup plex media server on the raspberry pi 3, and there it was at the very end of the line in /boot/cmdline.txt

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait ip=192.168.1.36
```

Above all else, document, document, document, this pi had historically pulled the .36, but to conform to my desires I made it .34 to align with my ip scheme.  Thanks all for looking and those that offered assistance.  Hopefully this will be a lesson for others.

Comment: And the lesson is DO NOT USE A STATIC ADDRESS and if you do DON"T PUT IN `/boot/cmdline.txt`